# insert in for loop fails

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I'm trying to insert in a for loop to a Stringbuilder but it crashes. This is my code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This is a text");
for(int i = 0;i < sb.length();i++){
    if(sb.charAt(i) == 't'){
        sb.insert(i, 't');
    }
}
```

Purpose of this is to double every 't'.

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: This creates an infinite loop, doesn't it? StackOverflowError? Because of the last `t`?

Comment: Why are you not using the `String.replace` method - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29?

Comment: That would also have been a good solution thanks. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting an `OutOfMemoryError`, because you don't skip the `t` character that you're doubling.

```
This is a text
          ^
This is a ttext
           ^
This is a tttext
            ^
```

This continues until you've run out of memory.

You must skip the `t` that you just added by incrementing `i` just after inserting the doubled `t`.

```
if (sb.charAt(i) == 't')
{
    sb.insert(i, 't');
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. But I only determined the error by running your code.  In the future, please include the error/exception message and stack trace.  That makes it easier to diagnose the problem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a StringBuilder and the string like this:

```
String currentText = "This is a text";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < currentText.length(); i++){
    sb.append(currentText.charAt(i));
    if(currentText.charAt(i) == 't'){
        sb.append('t');
    }
}
```

With that solution, you will not have the problem with a never ending loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the following.

1. Iterate through the list, from start to finish.
2. If you find a `t` add a `t`.

Two scenarios, either there is at least 1 `t` in the `String` or there are none. If there are none then all will work, the code does nothing. However if there is a `t` it will find that `t` add another `t`, the next character to check will now be... a `t`!. Infinite loop.

You can go around the problem by either by incrementing `i` (`ì++`) or by using `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you find a `t` this instruction `sb.insert(i, 't')` add `t` in position `i` and previous `t` become in position `i+1`, so when `i` will increment in the end of `for` loop with `i++` you deal another time with same letter `t`. so that will cause infinity loop.

To fix that you should increment `i` with `i++` in `if` block like that:

```
if(sb.charAt(i) == 't'){
sb.insert(i, 't');
i++;
}
```